# jQuery keyup not working on cloned input

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why keyup not working on cloned inputs? Thanks!

here is code:

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="text"/></li>
</ul>
<a href="#">new</a>
```

js:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var children = $("ul li:first").clone();
  $("ul li:last").after(children);
});

$('input').on("keyup", function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'yellow'});    
});
```

fidde: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LwKLy/)

Comment: Have you search the SO? This question has been asked n times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.clone(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to also clone events. (See the optional parameter in the documentation).

http://jsfiddle.net/4mNG4/

Or use event delegation:

```
$(document).on("keyup", 'input', function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'yellow'});    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass true to the clone method to include event bindings

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwKLy/1/)

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var children = $("ul li:first").clone(true);
  $("ul li:last").after(children);
});

$('input').on("keyup", function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'yellow'});    
});
```